# Run command on custom key binding

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, commands

I am trying to customize emacs/spacemacs to run a command after a key stroke, like running `eslint --fix` command on the buffer to fix errors.

I already tried

```
(defun fix-errors-with-eslint ()
  (shell-command-to-string (format "eslint --fix %s" buffer-file-name)))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-f") 'fix-errors-with-eslint)
```

but i receive an error: `Wrong type argument: commandp, fix-errors-with-eslint`

I am an emacs beginner, using only basic spacemacs and its layers, any help appreciated.

Comment: Check the Elisp manual for `interactive`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030409/5203563

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding (interactive) as the first line in your function definition. That will make it a command instead of a function.

Comment: could you post an example, again, I am a beginner :(

Comment: ok, that solve my problem